# Calling methods in C++ dll from C# without any info, only header files

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a third-party DLL that I am trying to write a wrapper for in C# and have C++ sample code, which works, but when I try calling the methods in the DLL, I get the error:

*Unable to find an entry point named 'scan' in DLL 'scard-com.dll'.*

Please help to point out my problem:

Here is part of the .h file used in the sample C++ app

```
interface ISCard_CardReaderDevices : IUnknown {
virtual UINT __stdcall scan(void) = 0;
virtual UINT __stdcall getDeviceCount(void) = 0;
virtual const CHAR * __stdcall getDeviceName(UINT id) = 0;
virtual const CHAR * __stdcall getSerialName(UINT id) = 0;
virtual ISCard_CardReader * __stdcall connectById(UINT id) = 0;
virtual ISCard_CardReader * __stdcall connectByName(const CHAR *name) = 0;
virtual ISCard_CardReader * __stdcall connectBySerial(const CHAR *serial) = 0;
virtual BOOL __stdcall disconnect(ISCard_CardReader *reader) = 0;
virtual ISCard_SecMsg * __stdcall attachSecMsg(ISCard_CardReader *reader) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detachSecMsg(ISCard_SecMsg *secMsg) = 0;
virtual ISCard_Script * __stdcall attachScript(ISCard_CardReader *reader) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detachScript(ISCard_Script *script) = 0;
virtual ISCard_IsoCard * __stdcall attachIsoCardByReader(ISCard_CardReader *reader) = 0;
virtual ISCard_IsoCard * __stdcall attachIsoCardBySecMSG(ISCard_SecMsg *secMsg) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detachIsoCard(ISCard_IsoCard *isocard) = 0;
virtual ISCard_MTCOS * __stdcall attachMTCOSByReader(ISCard_CardReader *reader) = 0;
virtual ISCard_MTCOS * __stdcall attachMTCOSBySecMSG(ISCard_SecMsg *secMsg) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detachMTCOS(ISCard_MTCOS *os) = 0;
virtual ISCard_IcaoConverter * __stdcall attachIcaoConverter(void) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detachIcaoConverter(ISCard_IcaoConverter *icaoconv) = 0;
virtual ISCard_ImageConverter * __stdcall attachImageConverter(void) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detachImageConverter(ISCard_ImageConverter *imgconv) = 0;
#ifdef MULTIAPP_EXT
virtual ISCard_IDLConverter * __stdcall attachIDLConverter(void) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detachIDLConverter(ISCard_IDLConverter *idlconv) = 0;
virtual ISCard_sscdConverter * __stdcall attachSSCDConverter(void) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detachSSCDConverter(ISCard_sscdConverter *sscdconv) = 0;
virtual ISCard_eHealthConverter * __stdcall attacheHealthConverter(void) = 0;
virtual void __stdcall detacheHealthConverter(ISCard_eHealthConverter *eHealthconv) = 0;
#endif // MULTIAPP_EXT
};
```

In my C# project, I have added this class:

```
public class SCardWrapper
{
    [DllImport("scard-com.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern uint scan();

// And call it like this:

public int listReaders()
    {
        try
        {
            uint numreaders = scan();
            if (numreaders < 1)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numreaders; i++)
            {
                IntPtr iDevice = getDeviceName(uint.Parse(i.ToString()));
                String sDevice = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(iDevice);
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : " + sDevice, i));
            }
            return int.Parse(numreaders.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

But as soon as it hits the scan() method, I get the error above. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There is no `scan` in the part of the header you posted.

Comment: The word "COM" in the DLL name is notable.  As is the declaration in the header, that's a COM interface.  No, they don't export these functions.  You simply add a reference to the type library.  Usually embedded in the DLL itself, so use Project > Add Reference > Browse button > select scard-com.dll.

Comment: Sorry, added the wrong Interface's description, edited post to show correct one.

Comment: Trying to add the DLL as a reference to my C# project in VS doesn't work, I get an error "Make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

Comment: `IUnknown` definitely looks like COM interface. Read [COM Interop: Client Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

P/Invoke doesn't *really* support C++. You're trying to call a method on an interface, not a C-style function.

There are some hacks that can get you the results you want, but usually by far the best option is writing a C++/CLI interop library you can use from your C# project.

Also, in general, header files aren't enough to properly call a native library. You need the documentation - there's noöne to hold your hand on issues like "How big is the string buffer supposed to be? Who is responsible for allocating/freeing the memory? What happens when the buffer isn't large enough? What are the possible error conditions?" If you don't have the documentation, there's little you can do but enjoy the reverse engineering :)

Answer (score 0):

Such `scan` declaration:

```
public class SCardWrapper
{
    [DllImport("scard-com.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern uint scan();
}
```

is a binding for a function with name `scan` from DLL `scard-com.dll`. Check that this function in your `scard-com.dll` DLL interface. To do that you could use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

`scan` name can be [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) in your DLL. In this case you could define it as `extern "C"` in your unmanaged code or add `EntryPoint = "mangled_scan_name"` to your PInvoke declaration.

By the way, `scan` is not a part of `interface ISCard_CardReader` above. But if it is a method of a class, than `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` is incorrect.